# Removing a detached instance

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to remove an object gives the following error:

> javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a
>   detached instance.

My code:

```
public void remover(MensagemContato param) {
    PersistenciaMensagemContato pParam = new PersistenciaMensagemContato();     
    pParam.delete(param);
    pParam.close();
}
```

Has anyone experienced this problem in a simple deletion of an object using hibernate?

Thanks!

Debora

Comment: Where does your param instance come from ?
No link but why are you instanciating and then closing your DAO ? Can we see the PersistenciaMensagemContato content ?

Comment: In Hibernate, a detached instance means that the current instance is not associated to any session. So, before deleting this instance,  you have to make sure that MensagemContato was previously persisted in a the database.

Comment: Can you show us how `PersistenciaMensagemContato` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ID specified in your `PersistenciaMensagemContato` entity. How will Hibernate know which reference to delete?

Comment: Apologies but I'm new at this. How do I do this?

Comment: Each entity **must** have a primary key. That primary key must match the database primary key. Google on how to do ORM with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete an entity that does'nt come from database.
You can only delete entities with ID values.

Answer (score -1):

[This is a good tutorial....  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm)

```
public void deleteEmployee (Integer EmployeeID){
  Session session = factory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Employee employee =
                    (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID);
        session.delete(employee);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```